# I want to see 3D model in Android Webview

Tags: android, google-chrome

I want to see 3D model in Android Webview.
Lots of Android smartphones can be able to seen 3D model by WebView, **But**, One product, named **'Galaxy Note Pro 12.2'** cannot be able to seen.

First, I give you some options.

1. My Chrome(chromium) version is 48.0.2564.109.
2. Android version is 5.0.2(Lollipop)
3. WebGL is newest version.

Now, I give you some example codes.

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setBlockNetworkImage(false);
    webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19){
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    }

    webSettings.setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 5 Build/LMY48B; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Mobile Safari/537.36");
    webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_multiple_renderers");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

very easy code I think.

I already set permission.
When I use other portable products(like galaxy smart phone), no problems are happen. But, Only above product can't.
Also, I already check **chrome://flags**
I read other questions, and do everything, but my problem doesn't solve.

How can I do?
Are there any missing checks?

Answer (score 0):

Webview is not well support by the device, I recoment use the XWalkView of [CrossWalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) to replace the webview. XWalkView supports well with the device that not support in the webview.

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858878/6521116) of mine about how to render 3D models with three.js in XWalkView.

Hope it helps.